# Logging to remote location

Tags: ruby, logging

I'm writing a client application which runs on a users computer and sends various requests to a server.

What I'd like to do is make logs from the client programs available on the server so that issues can be easily detected.

So, what I was thinking was to make the client log to a remote location over http.

Is this a good idea and are there any gems or libraries that will facilitate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [DRb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html) + [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) for this. Both are part of the Ruby standard library, so you don't even need to install any gems on either machine.

Here's how it works:

**Remote Logging Machine**

```
require 'drb'
require 'logger'

DRb.start_service 'druby://0.0.0.0:9000', Logger.new('foo.log', 'weekly')
DRb.thread.join
```

**Machine Doing the Logging**

```
require 'drb'

$log = DRbObject.new_with_uri 'druby://remote.server.ip:9000'

begin
  $log.info "Hello World"
rescue DRb::DRbConnError => e
  warn "Could not log because: #{e}"
  # Optionally re-log the message somewhere else.
end

puts "Yay, still running!"
```

I just tested this between two machines 1500 miles apart, where the client machine is even behind NAT, and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: This is great but there is one problem in that the client dies if the remote logger dies which isn't ideal.

Comment: @duckyfuzz Then wrap the logging call in a [begin/rescue](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_exceptions.html#handlingexceptions) clause. You know, this isn't the only thing that could go wrong in your application, and you need to be prepared to handle all errors that you cannot tolerate. I've edited my answer to show you how to use this basic feature of Ruby.